# Link a makefile for using SDL librarie

Tags: c, makefile, sdl

I'm learning using the SDL librarie, with a french site. 
This is the tuto :

"There may be some of you who have gotten into the habit of compiling by hand under Linux using a Makefile (file controlling compilation).
If this is your case, I invite you to download a Makefile which you can use to compile SDL projects.

The only thing a little special is the addition of the SDL library for the linker (LDFLAGS). You will have to download the Linux version of the SDL and install it in your compiler folder"

I've found my gcc folder in /usr/bin/gcc , but when I want to move the makefile to this folder, the error is :

```
mv: cannot move 'makefile_sdl' to '../usr/bin/makefile_sdl': Permission denied
```

There it is my make file, maybe something's wrong or missing (i'm a beginner ahah)

```
CPP=gcc    #compiler command
CFLAGS=-O3 #Option d'optimisation du programme
LDFLAGS=-lSDL -lSDL_mixer #Linker
EXEC=nomProgramme  #Nom du programme à modifier

all: ${EXEC}

${EXEC}: ${EXEC}.o
       ${CPP} $(CFLAGS) -o ${EXEC} ${EXEC}.o ${LDFLAGS}

${EXEC}.o: ${EXEC}.c
       ${CPP} $(CFLAGS) -o ${EXEC}.o -c ${EXEC}.c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to name your Makefile `Makefile`. Case sensitive, make sure to check for spelling errors, etc. You also need to be in the same directory as `Makefile` when you run `make`.

You should also just run `make` without any specified targets. It will automatically build the `all` target, which will build your program into an executable called `nomProgramme`.

You'll also need to install `libsdl-mixer1.2-dev` (`sudo apt-get install libsdl-mixer1.2-dev` and change `EXEC=main` back to `EXEC=nomProgramme`.

Here's a link to the GNU `make` documentation. It gives a quick overview and then a very detailed explanation of everything you can do with GNU `make`: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html

Comment: No, you do not need to change the name of your make file.  Rather use the `-f` parameter, followed by your current makefile name

Comment: @user3629249 And make everyone who builds your software ever use `make -f makefile_sdl` instead of simply just `make`? I don't think so. And anyway, the OP didn't know Makefile naming conventions prior to asking this question.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to (and shouldn't) move the makefile to `/usr/bin`.

You can put it anywhere, but things will be easier if it's in the same directory as your source code (`nomProgramme.c`).

Answer (score -1):

to answer the OPs question:

the directory `/usr/bin` is not writable via user (like yourself).

However, executing a command line that is prefixed with `sudo` (giving you 'root' privileges) will enable you to write on that directory.

However, `/usr/bin` is intended for executable files and `Makefile_sdl` is NOT an executable file

Suggest saving that file 'somewhere' Then when you want to use that makefile, to copy it to the directory where your current project is located (I.E. the directory in which you want to run `make`

However, `Makefile_sdl` is not one of the standard file names recognized by `make` so must run `make` via:

```
make -f Makefile_sdl
```